# Issue with fetching value from an excel in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am able to fetch the values from an excel sheet, I have 20 columns in my sheet where 7th and 8th columns are date type cells like **7-Mar-2015**, I am able to fetch the string/text values properly but not able to fetch the date format cells, and getting an error, I tried changing the type to get the cell values but not happening, can anyone help me how can I get both text/String OR Date format cells in my while loop,'

My code is as follows,

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Map<Field, String> values = new EnumMap(Field.class);
            for (Field f : Field.values()) {
                Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(f.ordinal());
                if (cell != null) {
                    values.put(f, cell.getStringCellValue());
                }
            }
```

The date format is **7-Mar-2015**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to check the format of the cell and then extract the value with correct funtion,

for reference,

```
if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
        } else {
            System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        }
}
```